# Jasper Viewer set title

Tags: java, swing, jasper-reports

Here is how I show the Jasper report in swing applications.

```
 JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint, true);
```

Then when the report is viewed, the report viewer's title is "Jasper Viewer" . I want to change it and set my own title name. My other question is how to directly send the report to the print without viewing.Please give any sample code.Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`JasperViewer.viewReport(...)`is a wrapper class that creates and shows a `JasperViewer` `JFrame` with a `JRViewer` panel.

Using this method you can't access the underlying `JFrame`, so you can't change the frame title.

You can try to create your own `JasperViewer` frame using the public constructor, and then set the title using the `setTitle(...)` method.

Another and recommended approach is to create a custom `JDialog` with a `JRViewer` panel.

To print your report without viewing:

```
final JRPrintServiceExporter exporter = new JRPrintServiceExporter();
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
exporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.DISPLAY_PAGE_DIALOG, Boolean.FALSE);
exporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.DISPLAY_PRINT_DIALOG, Boolean.TRUE);
exporter.exportReport();
```

Answer (score 9):

What I normally do is :

```
        JasperViewer jv = new JasperViewer(jasperPrint, false);
        jv.setTitle("Report-Title");
        jv.setVisible(true);
```

This works because, JasperViewer is a JFrame -

```
public class JasperViewer extends JFrame{
   //...
}
```